# Why was Marty the last child to fade out?

Tags: back-to-the-future

As we know, Marty McFly from *Back to the Future* is the third child in the McFly family in 1985.  In *BTTF I* we see in the picture of all three children that they progressively fade out.  I understand why this is the case, but **why would Marty be the *last one* to fade out and not the first, as he was the last one born**?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that the changes in the timeline cascade forward, affecting temporally displaced facts in order of how far removed they are from the moment of distortion.  Marty faded last because his birthday is the furthest away.

Were it not for his siblings fading in the same order relative to each other, it might also be possible that Marty's displacement itself offered him some kind of protection.